# Excel treating date column as general but I need it to treat it as Date when exporting to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am using Visual Studio and writing code in C# to read an excel then format the excel worksheet to what i want then export it back into an excel. After exporting to Excel, when I open that file, it treats the date column as "General" unless I right click on it and set its type to "Date".  I need excel to read it as "Date."  The date is formatted correctly but Excel not reading it as a Date.  Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.  It's alot of code so I hope this is enough for someone to understand what I am trying to do.[image]

```
// Excel rows are cell arrays so loop through once to determine 
        // the actual table geometry
        int firstRow = xlSheet.FirstRowNum;
        int lastRow = xlSheet.LastRowNum;
        int firstCol = xlSheet.GetRow(firstRow).FirstCellNum;
        int lastCol = xlSheet.GetRow(lastRow).LastCellNum;

        for (int rowIdx = firstRow; rowIdx < lastRow; rowIdx++)
        {
            var r = xlSheet.GetRow(rowIdx);
            if (r == null) { continue; } //  Nothing here, move on to the next record

            int thisFirstCol = xlSheet.GetRow(rowIdx).FirstCellNum;
            int thisLastCol = xlSheet.GetRow(rowIdx).LastCellNum;
            firstCol = Math.Min(thisFirstCol, firstCol);
            lastCol = Math.Max(thisLastCol, lastCol);
        }
        
        // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"First Row/Col:{firstRow} / {firstCol}  Last Row/Col {lastRow} / {lastCol}");

        // Set up the column headers
        for (int colIdx = firstCol; colIdx < lastCol; colIdx++)
        {
            string colName = $"field{colIdx}"; //default
            if (useHeader)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Only if firstRow isn't the header, otherwise you should choose useHeader = false
                    // when calling this from the adapter.
                    // Duplicate column name is rare, but it happens.
                    colName = xlSheet.GetRow(firstRow).GetCell(colIdx).ToString().Trim();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(colName) || dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
                    {                           
                        colName = $"field{colIdx}";
                    }
                }
                catch { } // May not have one, so the default will be used 
            }
            dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
        }

        // Now loop again to populate the data
        DataRow dr = null;
        if (useHeader) { 
            firstRow++;
            lastRow++;
        }
        for (int rowIdx = firstRow; rowIdx < lastRow; rowIdx++)
        {
            var xlRow = xlSheet.GetRow(rowIdx);
            if (xlRow == null) { continue; } //  Nothing here, move on to the next record

            dr = dt.NewRow();

            // We have to account for a bizarre -1 first column index on some Excel files, Gordon is an example
            // Datacolumns always start at 0, so we'll increment it independently, the count should be the same
            // in theory...
            int dtColIdx = -1;
            for (int colIdx = firstCol; colIdx < lastCol; colIdx++)
            {
                dtColIdx++;

                try
                {
                    // Convert the value to a reasonable format
                    ICell cell = xlRow.GetCell(colIdx);
                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        switch (cell.CellType)
                        {
                            case CellType.Formula:
                                dr[dtColIdx] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                                break;

                            case CellType.Numeric:
                                if (DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell))
                                {
                                    // TODO: DateTime vs Date vs Time check
                                    dr[dtColIdx] = cell.DateCellValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                  //  string xx = dr[dtColIdx].ToString();
                                  //  xlSheet.GetColumnStyle(dtColIdx).DataFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";
                                    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dr[dtColIdx] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                                }
                                break;

                            default:
                                dr[dtColIdx] = cell.ToString();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // May be nothing at this address, plug it with a blank                        
                    dr[dtColIdx] = String.Empty;
                }

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        //GenFieldParseCode(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: What technology are you using?  What type is `dt`?

Comment: @Flydog57 DT is data table, using like this                                                        public DataTable LoadXL(bool useHeader, string sheetNameOrNumber = "1")
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("carrier");

Comment: Who knew.  It looks like the right way to do this is likely to use `DataTableCellToExcelCellConverting` (https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-export-datatable-dataset-to-excel/501).  I've only done something like this using the OpenXML SDK.  Getting Excel dates right is tricky.  But, as someone else pointed out, Excel dates are floating point numbers (integer part is #days past the epoch, the fractional part is out of 24 hours) formatted as a date.  Enter `12345.75` into an Excel cell and you'll see it's 6:00pm on 18-Oct-1993 if you format it as a data/time.

Comment: There's actually an intentional bug in the Excel epoch.  The bug enable bug-for-bug compatibility with Lotus 123 way back when: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: How are you writing from DataTable to Excel?
Are you using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel or OpenXML or other third-party interface ?

From the code which you have already given, during read, you seem to convert Date to string. would that changed data-type anyway affecting your write?

Comment: @GDC im using NPOI.SS.UserModel and that string does affect my write if it is not in that certain format "MM/dd/yyyy"